# Files touched in commits that are in current branch but not in master (for Jenkins)

Tags: git, bash, jenkins, eslint

I am trying to write a command to get all the files (as path/to/file) touched in the commits that are in my current branch but not in master.

To give some context, Jenkins will pass those files (when matching .jsx and .js) as arguments for `eslint` and publish the problems. I cannot run eslint on all the codebase because it was never parsed with a linter before, there is an endless number of errors.

This is what I have got so far:

> node node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js -f checkstyle $( $(printf 'npm run compare_master_current') | tail -n +5 ) --ext .jsx > eslint.xml;

where `compare_master_current` is:

> git log --pretty='format:' --name-only master..$(git branch | grep \* | awk '{print $2}')

They are both stored in my `package.json` as npm scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  "eslint:jenkins": "node node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js -f checkstyle $( $(printf 'npm run compare_master_current') | tail -n +5 ) --ext .jsx > eslint.xml; exit 0",
  "compare_master_current": "git log --pretty='format:' --name-only master..$(git branch | grep \\* | awk '{print $2}')"
}
```

My solution works but I am not an expert, so:
1) I cannot be sure it is errors-free
2) I cannot be sure it is the best way to do it (I am pretty confident there is room for improvement)

Any contribution will be very appreciated!

Thanks!

UPDATE: to make it works on Jenkins, I had to make this change:

```
"compare_master_current": "git log --pretty='format:' --name-only master.."
```

No idea why the downvote but I added Jenkins to the title, to make more clear what is the context of the command.

Comment: `git diff --name-only master...`

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to suppress errors in existing files would be to put this at the top of each file:

```
/* eslint-disable */
```

You can then always run eslint on the entire code base, and it will only report errors for the new files which don't have this suppression.

This way you can also gradually clean up existing errors file by file, and remove the suppression for those files.